# Java website on Tomcat PHP website on Apache - how to get PHP web pages into Java web pages?

Tags: apache, jquery, tomcat, php-java-bridge, mod-proxy-html

We have a Java web application deployed on Tomcat. We also setup Apache and mod_proxy_ajp to route web requests (port 80/443) to Tomcat.

We would like to deploy a PHP application on the same Apache server - probably under a subdirectory (/var/www/ourapp).

Now we would like to access & display web pages from PHP application within web pages generated by Java application. Planning to implement Single Sign-on as well. Example: Web page from java has (JQuery Tabs) and we like to display the PHP web page within a tab while all other HTML comes from java application.

Can you please give a overall picture of how to proceed about this?
Mainly 1. how we should install/setup our PHP application on same Apache server which is used to route web requests to Tomcat? i.e. either setup sub domain or install in sub directory
2. How to bring PHP pages into present web pages (generated by java). Can we use AJAX requests or should go for Java PHP Bridge/ Querces such applications?

Thank you for your time in advance. Regards.